# php left join with if else to show particular html button tag

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, left-join

hi i'm working on social media project something similar to facebook and instgram. here i have 2 tables one is Users table and another is Friendlist table where in users table i have all users who ever signup details and in friendlist table i have friend request relationship of one to many. evrything is working fine. now my condition is if the both friends are already friends then in friend list it show send msg else if no friends then it show add friend. (to check wheather friends or not i have column in mysql db as accept)

here is my db structure of friendlist:-

```
 friend_id | userid | friendId | accept | response |
 +-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
 |         1 |      4 |        1 |      1 |        1 |
 |         2 |      5 |        1 |      1 |        1 |
 |         3 |      2 |        4 |      1 |        1 |
```

and here is Users table:-

```
id | nickname      | email                 | ph_num  | password                         | 
profile_pic                      | status | Created_at          |
+----+---------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------------+- 
---------------------------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | prasanna      | prasanna@gmail.com    | 12345   | 0a2b75a016a758e08888d66ba244126f | 
1583493901_2020-02-14-110313.jpg |      1 | 2020-03-05 12:52:37 |
|  2 | demo          | demo@d.d              | 1234    | fe01ce2a7fbac8fafaed7c982a04e229 | 
NULL                             |      0 | 2020-03-05 14:15:51 |
|  4 | test          | test@g.g              | 56456   | 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 | 
1583494768_pic.png               |      0 | 2020-03-06 16:29:43 |
|  5 | one_more_user | onemoreuser@gmail.com | 9988776 | 57bc707659ecf8998c9251b3aae18bd0 | 
NULL                             |      0 | 2020-03-07 14:00:26 |
```

tried query :

```
$result = "SELECT u.*, f.friendId, f.userid, f.accept FROM Users u LEFT JOIN friendlist f ON 
u.id = f.userid";
$userlist = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
```

in while loop:

```
 <?php
       while ($list = $userlist->fetch_assoc()):?>
        <?php if ($_SESSION['id'] !== $list['id']):?>
        <li class="list-group-item"  >  
       <img class="onlineimg" src="../uploads/<?php echo $list['profile_pic']; ?>"/>
        <?php echo $list['nickname']; ?>
        <?php if ($_SESSION['id'] == $list['friendId']):?>
            <?php if ($list['accept'] ==  '0'):?>
        <p style="display: none" class="selected"><?php echo $list['id']; ?> </p>
        <button class="btn btn-success float-right"><span style="display: none"><?php echo 
       $list['id'] ?> </span> add friend</button>
       <?php endif ;?>
       <?php endif ;?>
        <?php if ($list['accept'] ==  '1'):?>
        <p style="display: none" class="selected"><?php echo $list['id']; ?> </p>
        <button class="btn btn-success float-right"><span style="display: none"><?php echo 
       $list['id'] ?> </span> send message</button>
       <?php endif ;?>
      </li>
    <?php endif ;?>
      <?php endwhile;?>
```

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qro3D.png)

from the above image the user demo is showing send message instead of add friend coz demo is not friend to the prasanna.

please help me to come through this i stuck here from past of some hours. thank you advance and sorry for my english grammer.

Comment: If you have to switch from html to php on nearly every single line, it will be cleaner just to stay inside php and use echoes.  I don't find it very clear where your script is broken or what your exact result set should be.  If this is a mysql issue, we don't need to see the "in while loop" snippet.  Please isolate the issue and show nothing more.

Comment: yes your right sir. but i have took css styling from bootstrap which includes special chars like - and all, and php echo will not allow it will through error of syntax error so i'm  using this way.

Comment: A db-fiddle.com demo link will help volunteers (especially ones like me who volunteer primarily from mobile phones) to attempt helping you.

Comment: okay just a moment let me try with db-fiddle.com

Comment: While doing this, please remove unnecessary columns from the schema like `password`.  We are looking for a [mcve] because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2943403.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8CVkj1bFDRrE7CcWx5VWjN/0 db fiddle

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you  @Strawberry

Comment: The most useful part of this question is buried deep down in the comments section

Comment: aah sorry, i'm not getting your point of view.@Strawberry

Comment: what is the meaning of echo [image][1]$list['id'] in your code?

Comment: that was by mistakenly add in between that wait i will fix that

Answer (score 1):

As per yor code logic the only help possible is comments added:-

```
if(session_id == friendID)
{
   if(accept == 0)
  {
    // add friend
  } //you are missing else condition here "what if accept == 1"
} //you are missing else condition here "what if session_id != friendID
//and code below does not belong here at all
 if(accept == 1)
  {
    // send message
  }
```

Comment: hi sandeep thank you for your response. in my code i used two if statements coz i was writting the php code in between of html tags. as the question is. and if i use your method i cant able to apply css classes. but thank you for your ans.

Comment: can you tell your requirement as i have answered. for a while forget about the html.